# LibreOfficePortable - shared drive / multi user

Tags: libreoffice, user-profiles, portable-apps

I'd like to use the binaries of LibreOfficePortable with more users in one shared drive, example:

Z:\LibreOfficePortable\LibreOfficeDrawPortable.exe

By default this is not possible as the profile is put into the same location as the app. So I suppose I will have to use a specific profile directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems there is no good answer to this question, so I post something which might worked for me:

1. Install LibreOffice on my PC
2. Copied the entire LibreOffice-folder to a shared drive
3. Created shortcuts to the binaries
4. Distributed the shortcuts to the users

Now people who occasionaly need LibreOffice can use it in Citrix, without it having to be installed in the image. Even so I do recommand installing it correctly if you need in regulary and have the possibility to do so.